# Missing includes for new OpenGL 4.5 features?

Tags: opengl

I want to use the new OpenGL 4.5 features, however if I use them (let's say 'glCreateTextures') it says

> > error: use of undeclared identifier 'glCreateTextures'

glGenTextures works with no problems, though.

OpenGL 4.5 is working, glGetString(GL_VERSION) says

> > 4.5.0 NVIDIA 340.23.01

Am I missing some new includes?

EDIT: I had to install GLEW 1.11, now it works :-)

Comment: Are you using any OpenGL extension library? GLEW for example? Its most recent version does have glCreateTextures available.

Comment: Given the fact that the OpenGL-4.5 specifications have been released only yesterday, I'd be very surprised if the changes had already permeated into all the support libraries out there.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that I need new GLEW too, thanks Bart!

Comment: There is already a new GLEW version (1.11.0) that supports OpenGL 4.5, however it is not yet in the repositories for Ubuntu 14.04